# Modifying a variable in javascript? Not Working

Tags: javascript, variables, global, local, pacman

I'm trying to make it so that when pacman runs into a ghost he loses a life. ANd that then according to the number of lives he has a specific message is displayed, however the variable doesnt seem to be taking into account that i'm changing it.

ANy suggestions?

```
var life=3;
// Lorsque l'on rencontre un fantome.
function manchePerdue()
{ 
  x_Pacman = 13;
  y_Pacman = 10;

  life = life-1;

  if (life=2) {
    window.alert("2 Lives Left");
  }
  else if (life=1) {
    window.alert("1 Life Left");
  }
  else { 
    window.alert("Game Over");
    gameover();
  }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment `==` is equality, check your if statements.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the equality operator `==` in your if's, not the assignment operator `=`.

```
if (life == 2) {
  alert("2 Lives Left");
else if (life == 1) {
  alert("1 Life Left");
} else {
  alert("Game Over");
  gameover();
}
```

Using `=` means you're reassigning the value in each for check. For example:

```
var lives = 3;
if (lives = 1) {
  alert("1 life"); // Will show up
}
alert(lives); // Will show "1"!
```

Javascript also has the idea of strict equality using the `===` operator. In the case of strict equality, the types must also match.

```
1 == 1; // true
1 == "1"; // true
1 === "1"; // false
```

For what it's worth, you'll also notice that you don't need to write `window.alert`, just writing `alert` will suffice because `window` is the global scope.